# having a button in an objective c file (from a pod) and subclassing it from swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

So I am currently using an SDK which has a XIB file and I have connected a button to its view controller as you see in the code below. I have done this within the pod library itself

```
- (IBAction)testButton:(UIButton *)sender {
NSLog(@"test");
}
```

I have then subclassed the class which I placed this method in my swift file. However, I am unable to access this button from the swift file itself. How do I override this button's functionality from my swift file itself?

```
class MyLoginViewController: BLoginViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

//I am unable to override the button in this view controller
```

Comment: You want to call that button action created in C to swift and your swift file has a button that you want to link it with button action declared in C class ?

Comment: `- (IBAction)testButton:(UIButton *)sender` the button is declared in interface or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this line in your BLoginViewController.h

```
- (IBAction)testButton:(UIButton *)sender;
```

now you can override this method in your MyLoginViewController like this

```
override func test(_ sender: UIButton!) {

}
```